# MailKit/MimeKit SMTP connect error

Tags: vb.net, smtp, mailkit, mimekit

While trying to send an e-mail using `MailKit` and `MimeKit`, I received the following error:

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection
>   attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
>   after a period of time, or established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond.

The vb.net code I'm using:

```
Dim mail As New MimeMessage()
mail.From.Add(New MailboxAddress("John DOE", "john.doe@hotmail.com"))
mail.To.Add(New MailboxAddress("Mary JANE", "mary.jane@yahoo.com"))
mail.Subject = "Hello!"
Dim sText As New TextPart("plain")
sText.SetText("UTF-8", "How are you Jane?")
mail.Body = sText

Using smtp = New SmtpClient()
    smtp.LocalDomain = "XX.XXX.XX.XXX"
    smtp.Connect("server33.somewebhosting.com", 465, False)
    smtp.Authenticate("myusername@somewebhosting.com", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
    smtp.Send(mail)
    smtp.Disconnect(True)
End Using
```

The time-out error occurs at this line:

```
smtp.Connect("server33.somewebhosting.com", 465, False)
```

The weird thing is that it works on my home computer, but not at work.

What do you think is the cause of the problem?

Comment: "but not at work" -- I would check with your work IT department to make sure you can connect to the SMTP server on port 465. It's probably a firewall or security system blocking the connection.

Comment: Mozilla Thunderbird works on my work computer with these settings.

Comment: But it could be a software firewall where Thunderbird is allowed to connect but IIS is not.

Answer (score 5):

SMTP port 465 is the SSL port and therefore the third argument to `Connect()` should be `True`, not `False`. In other words, change the code to this:

```
smtp.Connect("server33.somewebhosting.com", 465, True)
```

If SmtpClient still fails to connect after making that change, then it means that the server is unreachable.

To diagnose the problem:

1. make sure that the hostname and port are correct by contacting your administrator
2. make sure that you are not behind a firewall that is preventing you from connecting
3. make sure that the SMTP server is actually online